# Pull data from another list in sharepoint new item custom form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, spservices

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I need to fetch data from another list and insert it  in my new form(Custom form). But after fetching data from another list and setting all values, when i click on save it gives SharePoint WebPart error and only WebPart ID is given.

I don't know why this error is coming and how to solve it?
Even i tried SPServices to fetch information but it gives 500(internal server error.)

```
   $().SPServices({ 
operation: "GetListItems", 
async: false, 
listName: "Requests", 
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Application' /></ViewFields>", 
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where></Where></Query>", 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
{ var req = $(this).attr("ows_Application"); $("select[Title='Request']").append(new Option(req,req)); }); 
} 
});
```

Comment: please paste your code what you are trying..

Comment: $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Requests",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Application' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
var req = $(this).attr("ows_Application");
$("select[Title='Request']").append(new Option(req,req));
});
}
});

Comment: I changed my CDN and now List.asmx file is properly loaded, but Now its not detecting z:row.

Comment: please update you code in question in formatted version...

Comment: alert your xdata in complete function....like  alert(xData.responseXML.xml)

Comment: also why are you putting blank where condition ?

Comment: Programmers don't use ``alert``, learn to use the DEV console and trace your code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to perform the same operation. Code below uses rest api to fetch the data from the list and perform the same action which you are trying to do using SPServices.

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Requests')/items?$select=Title,Application",
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value) {
        $("select[Title='Request']").append(new Option(value["Application"], value["Application"]));
    });
},
error: function(data) {
    alert("Request Failed");
    console.log(data)
}
});
```